# hide my apps picture from gallery (exect use .nomedia)

Tags: android

I use this method to convert my bitmap file and then put these images uri in data base. but I want this folder "my_app" dose not show in gallery. what do I do?!
any solution exept use no media?!

```
public File bitmapConvertToFile(Bitmap bitmap){
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    File bitmapFile = null;
    try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_app/");
        if (!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
        }
        bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_app/"+"today_picture.jpg");
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(bitmapFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{bitmapFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
            @Override
            public void onMediaScannerConnected() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(CropImage.this,"saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (fileOutputStream != null){
            try {
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
    return bitmapFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_app/");
```

use

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir()+"/my_app/");
```

What this does is it saves your file inside the app so that it cannot be accessed by any other app except yours.

Hence your bimap file will be

```
bitmapFile = new File(getFilesDir()+"/my_app/"+"today_picture.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to save your pic in internal storage.
I have used this and this is working for me.

```
public void saveProfilePic(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/user_pic.png/");
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
```